# Hashcodes are same, but != returns true?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am stumped by a seemingly simple problem. I have two objects that I am comparing with a !=.

When I run the application, a != b is true.
When I put a breakpoint and do a Watch, a.GetHashCode() == b.GetHashCode() is true.

These two (reference type) objects are defined in a different assembly, but I cannot find an override to the != method (although GetHashCode is overridden). Is there another explanation for this? Could it be possible that a GetHashCode for two objects could be the same, but a not-overriden != would return true?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When two objects that are different return the same code it is called a "collision".  With only ~4 billion possible integer values, and more than 4 billion possible values of [your class name here] some collisions are inevitable.  This is why a hash based structure (i.e. `Dictionary`) can't rely entirely on `GetHashCode`, it also needs a sensible `Equals` implementation to be effective.  The `Equals` method is what is used to resolve these collisions.

Of course it's also possible that the creator of the class overwrite either `GetHashCode` or `Equals` and in some way made a mistake that in some way violated the "contract" for generating hash codes.  [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx) is one list of guidelines to keep in mind when creating your `GetHashCode` methods.  Remember that there is a fairly small set of things that you *have* to do, and another set of things that can be done to make it work *efficiently*.

`return 0;` is actually a perfectly acceptable `GetHashCode` implementation.  It conforms with all of the rules, it just has a 100% chance of causing collisions, so it will be extraordinarily *inefficient* and you shouldn't ever actually do that.

Comment: If one just happen to stumble upon a collision while debugging the  hash algorithm is most likely extremely bad.

Comment: @Magnus That depends entirely on the circumstances.  Did they just create two objects that happened to collide (odds are 1 in 4 billion), or did they create a lot of objects, assumed that the hash codes would be unique, and have their code break as a result?  In the second case the odds are `numberOfGeneratedObjects / ~4 billion`

Comment: sure you are right. By the way 1 in 4 billion assumes a perfect hash algorithm is used, in reality the odds are much lower. (unless the datatype is int32 which just returns itself.)

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly legal for two objects that are not equal to have the same hashcode, but it is not valid for two objects that are equal to have different hashcodes.

The Dictionary style collection classes use the hashcode value (the GetHashCode value returned from the object specified as the key) to put the key/value pair into a hashbin. All key/value pairs where the hashcode value is the same for the key go into the same hashbin. If the hashcode generation is effective it means there will be very few (hopefully one just one) key/value pairs in each non-empty hashbin in the dictionary.

When you access contents in the dictionary by specifying an object as a key, the pseudo logic for finding the correct value to be returned is:

1. Get the hashcode value for the object specified as the key in the request (GetHashCode())
2. If there is a non-empty hashbin for that hashcode, iterate over the key objects of all key/value pairs in that hashbin. For each key/value pair in the hashbin, check if the key  object Equals() the object that was passed in as the key to the request. If so, return the Value object in that key/value pair.

This is what makes dictionary lookups very effective compared to looking for an object in a List style collection (when the hashcode distribution is good).